# Dependence and independence of discrete random variables

Tags: random-variables, independence

A discrete random variable only takes integer values $1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ; 6$, with all the indicated values being equally probable. Let $Y(n)$-remainder of dividing $X$ by $n (n = 2 or n = 3)$. Is it true that $Y2$ and $Y3$ are not hanging. Solve the same problem if the distribution $X$ is proportional accepted values, i.e. $P (X = k) = A k, k = 1,. ... ... , 6$.

Building a general table

[image]

Now Y = 2 [image]

And Y=3

[image]

I have built tables for Y = 2 and Y = 3. But how now to check them for dependence or independence. Using the dependency definition won't work for us. Tell me, please

Comment: Can you verify that $P(Y_2 = 0 | Y_3 = 0) = P(Y_2 = 0)$? Can you repeat that logic for all pairs of values $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ take?

Comment: "*Using the dependency definition won't work for us*"  It should.

Comment: @StephenDonovan  I can check it, but I don’t understand why? Can you explain why we need this, please

Comment: @Ben This is equivalent to the definition of independence: multiplying both sides by $P(Y_3 = 0)$ yields $P(Y_2 = 0 \cap Y_3 = 0) = P(Y_2 = 0)P(Y_3 = 0).$ (you can check with this as well but I found the conditional probability a bit more intuitive)

Comment: I agree with the previous comments.  For illustration, consider the following example: the probability of a number chosen at random from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ being congruent to $\displaystyle (1) \pmod{3} = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}.$  Now, restrict the set of choices, to those elements that are congruent to $0 \pmod{2}$, namely $\{2,4,6\}.$  Then, the probability of a number chosen at random from $\{2,4,6\}$ being congruent to $\displaystyle (1) \pmod{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: In effect, if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and you are considering the set $S = \{1,2,\cdots, (m\times n)\}$, and you are considering the two events of a number chosen at random from set $S$ being congruent to $r_m$ mod $(m)$ and a number chosen at random from set $S$ being congruent to $r_n$ mod $(n)$, then the two events represented by $r_n$ and $r_m$ are **always** independent events.  Again, this is based on the premise that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @StephenDonovan That is, if $ P (0,0) = 1/6 = P (1/6) P (1/6) $, turn out to be equal, we conclude that they are independent, if not equal, then they are dependent dependent. In my case, they are not equal and Y2 is dependent on Y3?

Comment: @Ben Not quite: you should have that $P(Y_2 = 0) = P(X = 2 \cup X = 4 \cup X = 6) = P(X = 2) + P(X = 4) + P(X = 6) =$ $ \frac16 + \frac16 + \frac16 = \frac12,$ not $\frac16.$ (and similarly for $P(Y_3 = 0).$

Comment: @StephenDonovan  For the Y3=0 the same answer 1/2.

Comment: @Ben I disagree. For what values of $X$ does $Y_3 = 0$?

Comment: For $  X={3,6} $?

Comment: @Ben For $X = 1$ we should have $Y_3 = 1,$ since $1 = 3(0) + 1.$

Comment: @Stephen Donovan So for $Y3=0$ the answer will be $1/3$?

Comment: @Ben Should be. So we have $\frac16 = \frac12 \cdot \frac13$ and our condition is satisfied. You can do this similarly for all the other pairs of values to verify that they're independent.

Comment: The variables $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ also have a *joint* distribution table which you should be able to fill out after you list the values of $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ for each value of $X$.